# TensorFlow object detection API evaluate training performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have been using [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) on my own dataset. While training, I want to know how well the NN is learning from the Training set. So, I want to run an evaluation on both training and eval set and get accuracy (mAP) respectively during the training sessions.

My config file:

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 50
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 960
        width: 960
      }
    }
    number_of_stages: 3
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101'
      first_stage_features_stride: 8
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 8
        width_stride: 8
      }
    }
    first_stage_atrous_rate: 2
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.00999999977648
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.699999988079
    first_stage_max_proposals: 100
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        conv_hyperparams {
          op: CONV
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.00999999977648
            }
          }
        }
        predict_instance_masks: true
        mask_height: 33
        mask_width: 33
        mask_prediction_conv_depth: 0
        mask_prediction_num_conv_layers: 4
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.300000011921
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    second_stage_mask_prediction_loss_weight: 4.0
  }
}
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.003
          schedule {
            step: 3000
            learning_rate: 0.00075
          }
          schedule {
            step: 6000
            learning_rate: 0.000300000014249
          }
          schedule {
            step: 15000
            learning_rate: 0.000075
          }
          schedule {
            step: 18000
            learning_rate: 0.0000314249
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: 2.99999992421e-05
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: 3.00000010611e-06
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "./mask_rcnn_resnet101_atrous_coco/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "./map901_label_map.pbtxt"
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["./my_coco_train.record-?????-of-00005"]
  }
}
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  max_evals: 100
  num_visualizations: 25
}
eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "./map901_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["./my_coco_val.record-?????-of-00001"]
  }
}
```

I ran the script with these parameters

```
python model_main.py --alsologtostderr \
  --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
  --model_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --num_train_steps=24000 \
  --sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=25 \
  --num_eval_steps=100 \
  --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1
```

I think this will run an evaluation of Eval examples. To evaluate training data (to check how many features captured from training) I have added 
`--eval_training_data=True` to the parameters.

I can not add the "eval_training_data" on the go. I need to run 2 different training sessions.

Interestingly, with "eval_training_data" parameter added I got,

```
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.165
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.281
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.167
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.051
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.109
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.202
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.164
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.202
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.202
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.057
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.141
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.236
```

Whereas without "eval_training_data" I got

```
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.168
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.283
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.173
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.049
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.108
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.208
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.170
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.208
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.208
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.056
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.139
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.248
```

I just got confused. My questions are:

1. Does not "eval_training_data" force object detection API to run evaluation on the Training set?
2. Why in my case both scores are almost the same, in some cases eval score is better?
3. Which parameters need to add so that it evaluates both training and eval set separately during a training session and print it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I could gather with a quick look at the repo was :

1. eval_training_data evaluates only on the training set and excludes the eval set from the evaluation process. So it's running it on your training set only.
2. Scores being the same is not a bad thing. It's actually good and shows that your model is not overfitted which would be the case had the evaluation of training data scores been significantly higher than the evaluation scores for the evaluation data. The higher scores in some cases for the evaluation are because it must be a much smaller data set and hence fractions can vary much more with even a few cases of good or bad predictions.
   Also, the model is learning the features and associating it with classes rather than learning the examples, so don't expect it to perform amazingly on the training set since it has seen all of them.
   The better your model performs on the validation set means the better it is generalized.
3. If you turn eval_training_data = True, it's actually separately evaluating the training set already and in case it's set to false( which is by default), it's evaluating only the eval set separately. 
   I'm not sure if they have added the feature for evaluating both together, but you can do it with a very small change in the model_main.py. Just make this addition. It's not clean and optimized but I guess you see the point and can modify it accordingly.

```
flags.DEFINE_boolean('eval_training_data_and_eval_data', False,
                     'This will evaluate botht the training data and evaluation data sequentially')

  if FLAGS.checkpoint_dir:
    if FLAGS.eval_training_data_and_eval_data:

      name = 'training_data'
      input_fn = eval_on_train_input_fn
      if FLAGS.run_once:
        estimator.evaluate(input_fn,
                           steps=None,
                           checkpoint_path=tf.train.latest_checkpoint(
                               FLAGS.checkpoint_dir))
      else:
        model_lib.continuous_eval(estimator, FLAGS.checkpoint_dir, input_fn,
                                  train_steps, name)

      name = 'validation_data'
      # The first eval input will be evaluated.
      input_fn = eval_input_fns[0]
      if FLAGS.run_once:
        estimator.evaluate(input_fn,
                           steps=None,
                           checkpoint_path=tf.train.latest_checkpoint(
                               FLAGS.checkpoint_dir))
      else:
        model_lib.continuous_eval(estimator, FLAGS.checkpoint_dir, input_fn,
                                  train_steps, name)

  else:
    train_spec, eval_specs = model_lib.create_train_and_eval_specs(
        train_input_fn,
        eval_input_fns,
        eval_on_train_input_fn,
        predict_input_fn,
        train_steps,
        eval_on_train_data=False)

    # Currently only a single Eval Spec is allowed.
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
```

Also, make sure you're providing correct and distinct paths for your dataset as well. Note that if we optimized the hyperparameters based on a validation score the validation score is biased and not a good estimate of the generalization any longer. To get a proper estimate of the generalization we have to compute the score on another test set.